# php "foreach" change to only first

Tags: php, joomla

i have a code in php from joomla. its array of languages.. and it shows all languages.
how to change this code to display only the first of the language in array with all params as they are here??

thank a lot

```
<?php foreach ($list as $language) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars($language->link, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), ENT_NOQUOTES); ?>">     
<?php echo $params->get('full_name', 1) ? $language->title_native : strtoupper($language->sef); ?>
</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Not sure what $list looks like, but if you only want the first one, just use $list[0]

Comment: use $list[0] where? if i use it here <?php foreach ($list[0] as $language) : ?> it dont work

Answer (score 0):

ok. i get it..
its change foreach to

```
$language = $list[0];
```